# In a form, why doesn't a label's "for" attribute match up to a field's "name" attribute?

Tags: html, forms

I completely understand the benefits of using the "for" attribute on a label. I suppose this is a question about the HTML spec itself: Why would the Creators want to match up labels to an ID rather than use the "name" attribute on a field?

The field's name should be unique anyway, right? So, why add another attribute and extra HTML to the field when it seems like, 99% of the time, the field ID ends up being a direct match of the field name?

*Edit*

In the case of the radio button, as many of you have said, the name is not unique, but in that case, you wouldn't need the "for" element for the label because you could wrap the `label` around the field itself, correct?

Comment: field `name` shouldn't be unique. Watch for `<input type='radio'>`

Comment: In case of radio boxes name will be same.

Comment: Edited my question to include the case where radio buttons have the same name.

Comment: ID comes from XML name from HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` attribute is not always unique: radio buttons generally share the same `name`.

**EDIT**

Input's can be wrapped in label's, that's valid. But one can think of cases where you can't or don't want to wrap label's. For example if the label is separated from the input by other HTML.

Comment: Such a silly oversight ;)

Comment: Edited my question to include why I don't think this is a show stopper.

Comment: The usecase for `for` attributes for radio buttons is the same as for any other form control. You don't always want the label to be an ancestor of the control.

Answer (score 0):

The name isn't unique my friend!
Like Radio buttons btw ;)
And all the selectors are based on ID.

Example:

```
<fieldset>
 <label for="radio1">
 <input type="radio" name="allRadios" id="radio1">
 <label for="radio2">
 <input type="radio" name="allRadios" id="radio2">
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript function:

document.getElementsByName("allRadios") gives a array even when there's only one element with the name radio and document.getElementById("radio1") give one DOM element.

Example: